# Is it possible to generate end comments for html

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to generate comments for closing div tags, lets take this ex. into consideration **normal HTML**:

```
<div id="content">
...
...buch of html or whateve
</div>
```

**with comments :**

```
<div id="content">
    ...
    ...buch of html or whateve
    </div><!--End of content-->
```

and so on go trough each div element and comment the end of it ?

Comment: In what language or on what platform?

Comment: @Pekka Using javascript .. or whatever would be most effiecient

Comment: But where would you want to store the results when done in Javascript? I think this is a great idea for a tool but what is your use case? To process local files? Or to highlight things during debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var d = divs.length-1; d >= 0; --d) {
   var div = divs[d];
   var id = div.id;  // d.getAttribute("id")
   if (id) {
     var cmt = document.createComment("End of " + id);
     div.parentNode.insertBefore(cmt, div.nextSibling);
   }
}
```

Comment: No content was just example div .. I mean if div id or class is named content than the comments should say end of whatever its called

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery, this is very simple.

```
jQuery('div').after('<!--end of content-->');
```

EDIT:

```
jQuery('div').each(function(){ jQuery(this).after('<!-- end of '+jQuery(this).id + '-->');});
```

Comment: it's only end of content because content is the div id

Comment: No content was just example div .. I mean if div id or class is named content than the comments should say end of whatever its called

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, in PHP, using DOM :

Using PHP allows you to save it, or whatever you need to ; and as it's using DOM, which is quite standardized, translating this to another language shouldn't require too much work.

*(And, judging from a comment on your question, you didn't exclude other languages that JS)*

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div id="content">
...
...buch of html or whateve
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
for ($i = $divs->length - 1 ; $i > -1 ; $i--) {
    $div = $divs->item($i);
    if ($div->hasAttribute('id')) {
        $id = $div->getAttribute('id');
        $comment = $dom->createComment("End of {$id}");
        if($div->nextSibling) {
            $div->parentNode->insertBefore($comment, $div->nextSibling);
        } else {
            $div->parentNode->appendChild($comment);
        }   
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Which gets you the following HTML source :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<div id="content">
...
...buch of html or whateve
</div>
<!--End of content-->
</body></html>
```

A couple of things to note :

- DOM allows one to load and parse non-valid HTML
- And generates valid-HTML

And, about what this does :

- Load the HTMl string, using `DOMDocument`
- Search for all `<div>` tags
- Foreach `<div>` tag :

  - If it has an `id` attributes,
  - Get its value
  - Create a comment based on that value
  - And add it to the DOM, after the `</div>` tag

Another solution, thinking about it, would probably have been to use XPath, instead of `getElementsByTagName` + `hasAttribute`...